# Novel with a girl who can talk to animals. Intends to marry a man named/titled Kahn. Makes friend with a girl called Maya

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book was about a girl (I don't remember her name) who can talk to animals.

I remember that she had a friend cat, and in the beginning she asked the cat something like, "*how do I look?*" to which he replied "*like a human.*"

At one point she goes to marry this guy named or titled Kahn(?) and she makes friends with another girl named Maya who is really good swimmer. They travel through a desert together.

Comment: Do you remember any other details? How old you were when the book came out or what year it was when you were reading it? Also, do you remember anything about any other characters in the book? Anything in particular about the cat that stands out?

Comment: Kahn is a normal European surname.  Khan is a Turkic and Mongol title that is now used as a name or title in many Asian lands.  Several persons who used the title Khan were noted for massacring millions of people.  Knowing the difference between Kahn and Khan is rather important.

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Elissa's Quest](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/183680/phoenix-rising-1-elissas-quest-by-erica-verrillo/)* by Erica Verrillo. The book repeatedly mentions "the Khan" and a friend called Maya who can grunt and squeak and squawk with the animals.

**Khan**

> The Khan's wealth was legendary, and his palace was reputed to be the finest in the world. However, very few travelers had actually seen the interior of the Khan's Citadel, as it was surrounded by a vast stretch of desert.

**Maya**

> Elissa believed that Maya meant what she said. But no child, even one as clever as Maya, would be able to escape alone and unaided across the desert. She would need help. In spite of herself, Elissa couldn't help but think of Falk.

**Friend cat (Willie)**

> It was Willie, the cat, hunting for his evening meal.
>   “Oh!” said Elissa. “It's you. Have you seen Nana?”
>   The cat sat down and licked his back. “No,” he said. “Have you seen any mice?”
>   “No,” said Elissa, not that she would tell Willie if she had. As far as hunting was concerned, animals were on their own. She took a few steps toward the door and turned. “How do I look, Willie?”
>   The cat turned his luminous eyes to her. “Like a human.”

Comment: THIS IS IT. Thank you so much!